# Showing Array of annotations on MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

Searched everywhere, read every stack overflow, but still no luck. I am trying to display an array of annotations on an MKMapView. Here is my code:

```
  // in viewDidLoad
  self.mapView.delegate = self
  var artworks = [MyMKAnnotation]()
for x in self.locations2 {
    let artwork = Artwork(title: "title1", coordinate: x)
    artworks.append(artwork)
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
    self.mapView.addAnnotations(artworks)
    self.mapView.showAnnotations(artworks, animated: true)
}
```

OK, so the problem is, with the current code as above, the annotations show, but the map view is blank. Here is an image of what I'm seeing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOufd.jpg
I can make the map view appear if I take away the dispatch_async method, but then I just see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TXiL.jpg and then the annotations aren't there.

I don't think it's a problem with my viewForAnnotation method, but rather a threading problem. I've tried doing it on the main thread, on a background thread, and a mix of those, and setting the animations to false in the showAnnotations method, but nothing works. I also tried moving this to viewDidAppear, viewDidLayoutSubviews, but again nothing works. It's always either 1) annotations show, but no map view, or 2) map view shows but no annotations

This seems like it should be fairly simple. Anyone have any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Also: I have 2 devices, iOS 8 and iOS 9.2, and I'm testing on real devices with internet access, no simulator.

any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Are the coordinates super close together? Just want to make sure the map isn't super zoomed in.

Comment: They are within 2-3 blocks of each other. Exact ones are: let locations = [CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.030088, longitude: 84.488833), CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.029822, longitude: 84.489879), CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.030342, longitude: 84.49122)]

Comment: I changed one of the latitudes to 39, and it rendered properly. I got the same issue as you with the original coordinates. Must be a bug with MKMapview has trouble rendering with coordinates too close.